# How to position blocks within flex block?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to position two blocks in parent block - one in the top, another in the bottom. Parents are follow each other as in catalog for example. To reach my goal I'am using flexible layout

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">

        <div class="holder">
            <div class="content">
                First content block<br/>
                First content block<br/>
                First content block<br/>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item">

      <div class="holder">
          <div class="content">
              Second content block<br/>
              Second content block<br/>
              Second content block<br/>
              Second content block<br/>
              Second content block<br/>
              Second content block<br/>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS is (webkit prefixes are deleted from this, presence in jsfiddle)

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: stretch;
}
.item{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.holder{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-content:space-between;
    height: 100%;
}
.content{
    flex: 1; // Added
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.bottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2nowks6p/5/.

There is a problem in layout, because bottom block does not position in bottom.
Can anyone explain to me, why this happen?

As @ketan answear add `flex: 1` to .content solve problem in Firefox but not in Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your demo to make it work on chrome & Firefox.
I added a `display: flex;` on .item and `flex: 1;` on .holder

https://jsfiddle.net/2nowks6p/8/

Answer (score 1):

Just give `flex:1;` to `.content` will make bottom div to position bottom.

```
.content{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  flex:1;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nowks6p/4/)**